# Making a macro to generate a custom show in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, visual-studio-macros

I want to make a macro for PowerPoint, to generate a custom show, containing all the slides from my PowerPoint but in random order.
How would I do this?
I want to be able to run it and create different custom shows each time.

It's been 3 years since I used PowerPoint, and the only experience I have with VB was a little bit of VB6 in 2004.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the info [here](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00429.htm).

Sample:

```
Sub sort_rand()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myvalue As Integer
    Dim islides As Integer
    islides = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        myvalue = Int((i * Rnd) + 1)
        ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlideSorter
        ActivePresentation.Slides(myvalue).Select
        ActiveWindow.Selection.Cut
        ActivePresentation.Slides(islides - 1).Select
        ActiveWindow.View.Paste
    Next

End Sub
```